# How to keep iterating through loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I have my matlab code

```
usrinput = input('Enter Month: ', 's');
if strcmp(usrinput, 'July')
    disp('Summer')
elseif strcmp(usrinput, 'January')
      disp('Winter')
elseif strcmp(usrinput,'October')
disp('Fall')
elseif strcmp(usrinput, 'April')
disp('Spring')
end
```

Where you input a month and it gives you the season,
But every time I call the script (called month) and input a month in I have to call the script again to do another month.
How can I set it so that I don't have to call the script every time.
AKA after I type in July and it says Winter, it will automatically say "Enter Month:" again and I can type in a new month
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a infinite "while loop" using `while(1)`, also you can have a more elegant code using `switch`, here is the code:

```
while (1)
    usrinput = input('Enter Month: ', 's');
    switch usrinput
        case 'July'
            disp('Summer')
        case 'January'
            disp('Winter')
        case 'October'
            disp('Fall')
        case 'April'
            disp('Spring')
        case 'exit'
            break
        otherwise
            disp('Please enter a month.')
    end
end
```

The loop will be running until the user type 'exit'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ???

```
n = 10 
while n > 1
    n = n-1;
     usrinput = input('Enter Month: ', 's');
if strcmp(usrinput, 'July')
    disp('Summer')
elseif strcmp(usrinput, 'January')
      disp('Winter')
elseif strcmp(usrinput,'October')
disp('Fall')
elseif strcmp(usrinput, 'April') 
disp('Spring')
   end
end
```

details about the while are [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html)